# Javascript help from a student about IF statements in a function

Tags: javascript

i am trying to make an input box with a button which checks the input to see if the users input age is older than 18, the input age does not have to be exact as i just want to know how to do this

i believe i do this with an if statement to check if the input value is greater than a value i choose

can anyone help please i am lost and confused and can't work out if i can put the if statement in the function i created or create a new one

thanks in advance for having a look, hopefully i will be able to contribute back to the community later on in my course

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Java Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Enter Your Birthday to Proceed</h1>
    <input type="date" id="myDate" value="2001-01-01">
    <button onclick="MyFunction()"> Submit </button>
    <p id="demo"></p>
    <script>
    function MyFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;


    var year = parseInt(x.value.split('-')[0]);

    if (year > 1998) {

      alert("you are too young");
       }
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: "_can't work out if i can put the if statement in the function i created_" You can and should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `if` statement is one of the most fundamental components of most programming languages. In javascript, the syntax is this:

```
if (condition) {
  // then execute this code
}
```

The *condition* can be anything that is "truthy", that is, it can be resolved to true or false. For example, `x < 20` is a *true* condition if the variable `x` stores a value less than 20; otherwise it is *false*.

You can read more info on `if` statements [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

A function can contain any number of lines of code, so in your case, simply use the `if` statement after you have enough information to make the condition.

You are using an HTML5 [`<input type="date">`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date) element, which stores its result in its `value` property in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

```
var myDate = document.getElementById('myDate')
console.log(myDate.value) // --> "2017-10-3"
```

From your question, you are interested in the year, so you need to get that part by itself and convert it into a number.

```
var sections = myDate.value.split('-');
// console.log(sections) --> ["2017", "10", "3"]
var yearString = sections[0]; // get the first section
// console.log(yearString) --> "2017"
var year = parseInt(yearString);
// console.log(year) --> 2017
```

(**edit starts here**)

Once you have `year`, you compare it to the current year to determine age.

```
var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
var age = thisYear - year;
```

Now you are ready to build your `if`

```
if (age > 18) {
  alert("you are old");
}
```

Working example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Java Test</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Enter Your Birthday to Proceed</h1>
  <input type="date" id="myDate" value="1980-01-01">
  <button onclick="MyFunction()"> Submit </button>
  <p id="demo"></p>
  <script>
    function MyFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;

      var year = parseInt(x.split('-')[0]);
      var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear();
      var age = thisYear - year;

      if (age > 18) {
        alert("you are old");
      } else if (age <= 18) {
        alert("you are too young");
      }
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for the comment, i tried the function you mentioned, both typing by hand and then copy and pasting but the alert is not working no matter the number i input or if i change the value of the if statement condition

Comment: Sorry, I made several dumb mistakes (not a good technique for teaching, might I say!). My first mistake was missing that `x` was the *value* of the element, not the *element itself*. Secondly, I showed how to extract the full year from the date input, but I never compared it with the current year. I updated the question, this time with a working example. Please let me know if you have any questions or troubles.

Comment: thank you so much!, it all makes sense now, thanks for your time

Comment: No problem! In time, you will get this stuff down. Keep pushing yourself by following tutorials, and don't forget to have fun building your own projects too!